# How long do 3DS Streetpass Relays keep info?

Tags: streetpass

The newest firmware updates in the US enabled Streetpass relays at McDonald's and Starbucks locations.

I walk by a McDonald's location every weekday morning on my way to work.

Assuming I get John's Streetpass today and let him into my plaza today, will I get that same Streetpass if I walk by McDonald's tomorrow? How long will John's (or my) Streetpass data be relayed from that same point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Streetpass relay points only store data from one system at a time for each game.

Let's assume you and John only have Mii Plaza games in common. John tags the relay first, and it saves his data, but doesn't send him anything. Then you tag the relay and get John's data. If you tag the relay the next day and John has tagged it again in the meantime, you'll get John's latest tag, but if you were the last one to tag the relay then you won't get anything.

Now let's say you and I both have game XYZ (with Streetpass functionality) and John doesn't. You tag the relay first and get nothing, but the relay stores your data for Mii Plaza and XYZ. Then John tags the relay and gets your data for Mii Plaza. Then, if I tag the relay, I'll get your data for XYZ and John's data for Mii Plaza.

The data does not expire (as far as Nintendo has disclosed). So if you tag the relay today, no one tags it for an entire year, and then John tags it after that, he should still get your data.

I hope that helps.

Also, here's Nintendo's explanation: http://www.nintendo.com/3ds/nintendozone?relay=on

Comment: The way I'm reading your answer, I'm understanding it that everyone who tags the relay after me will get my - or the first 10 passes sitting in the relay. Or is it first-in-last-out?

Comment: I didn't say any of that, please re-read the first line of my answer. Only first first person who tags the relay after you will get your data, but this applies separately for each game. Your data on the relay will then be replaced by their data.